# Error message when using "Add current select to filter" in Excel connected to Cube

Tags: excel, ssas, pivot-table, business-intelligence, olap

I have an Excel pivot table connected to SSAS cube and it works fine.

But got a problem when filtering dimension attribute (using "Add current select to filter") on the Row Labels. Excel shows the following error msg:

> [Error message shows here: XML parsing failed at line 1, column
>   779979: Illegal xml character. .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XOAr.jpg)

**[mouse over the member](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDhEb.jpg)**

Does anybody know what causes an issue and how to fix it?
I don't think there is something wrong with cube or data since it was successfully processed. Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Can you mouse over the member in question so the tooltip pops up and take a screenshot. I am looking for any odd old dates in a member property. What version of Excel? If you go to the FILE menu and choose About Excel it should give you an exact version. Is SSAS Multidimensional rather than SSAS Tabular?

Comment: Hi @GregGalloway, Thanks for your reply. I have added screenshot above. The cube is Multidimensional and it is Excel 2010, version 14.0.7162.500 (32-bit).

Comment: mouse over one of the SENTIDO members and you should see a tooltip pop up with some member properties. I am looking for a date member property first. Then I would look for a very old date in that property. What member properties do you have?

Comment: Ok. I attached the screenshot above. There is no date member by the way.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't sound like a bug I have hit in the past then. I would consider upgrading to a newer Excel or opening a support case